# Query to get column values as column name in mysql query

Tags: sql, mysqli, mysql-python

I have two tables Case, Build and Result as below
Table Case

```
......................................
: name  : description  : created_by  :
:.......:..............:.............:
: test1 : hello test1  : user        :
: test2 : hello test2  : user        :
:.......:..............:.............:
```

Table Build

```
.......................................
:  name  : description  : created_by  :
:........:..............:.............:
: build1 : hello build1 : user        :
: build2 : hello build2 : user        :
:........:..............:.............:
```

Here is my Result table

```
case_name   case_description    build_name  status
test1   hello test1 build1  Pass
test2   hello test2 build1  Fail
test1   hello test1 build2  Fail
test2   hello test2 build2  Pass
```

I need the query to get results in below format

```
....................................................
: case_name : case_description : build1 : build2:
:...........:..................:.........:.........:
:  test1    :   hello test1    :  PASS   :  FAIL   :
:  test2    :   hello test2    :  FAIL   :  PASS   :
:...........:..................:.........:.........:
```

Comment: What have you tried to get the result you want?

Comment: Can there only be two builds?  Will the two always be identified as "build1" and "build2"

Comment: What have you tried so far?????

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it; it's not elegant but gets the job done:

```
SELECT case_name, case_description
       MAX(CASE WHEN build_name = 'build1' THEN status ELSE '' END) AS build1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN build_name = 'build2' THEN status ELSE '' END) AS build2
FROM Result
GROUP BY case_name, case_description
```

If you have more than two builds, you can just add `MAX` statements appropriately (easy enough to do if you are constructing this query inside a Python script). As I said, not elegant, but a quick and easy way to do cross-tab queries.